# Using Bootstrap's Product example and trying to figure out how I add images

Tags: html, image, bootstrap-4, responsive-images

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and using their Product example as a base: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/product/

I'm trying to figure out how to change the white and gray background areas into actual photos of the product. The full code snippet is below but the colored blocks I am trying to change into responsive images is:

```
 <div class="bg-dark shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
```

Full Code Snippet:

```
<div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 pl-md-3">
  <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
    <div class="my-3 p-3">
      <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
      <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-dark shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-primary mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center text-white overflow-hidden">
    <div class="my-3 py-3">
      <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
      <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-light shadow-sm mx-auto" style="width: 80%; height: 300px; border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Either use a background image on the div with class `bg-light shadow-sm mx-auto` or put an image tag inside that div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use image inside div as follow:

```
        <div class="d-md-flex flex-md-equal w-100 my-md-3 pl-md-3">
            <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
                <div class="my-3 p-3">
                    <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
                    <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-white shadow-sm mx-auto screenshot-card">
                    <img style="height:auto;width:100%" src="/images/1.png", class="mx-auto w-65 lg:w-81">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bg-light mr-md-3 pt-3 px-3 pt-md-5 px-md-5 text-center overflow-hidden">
                <div class="my-3 py-3">
                    <h2 class="display-5">Another headline</h2>
                    <p class="lead">And an even wittier subheading.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="bg-white shadow-sm mx-auto screenshot-card">
                    <img style="height:auto;width:100%" src="/images/1.png", class="mx-auto w-65 lg:w-81">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You can use following class for screenshot-card

```
.screenshot-card {
    width: 80%; 
    height: 100%; 
    border-radius: 21px 21px 0 0;
 }
```